# Pycharm remote SSH "this IDE build has expired"

Tags: pycharm, remote-server

I used to use my PyCharm IDE for remote development on a CentOS machine. All of a sudden it stopped working. The admin said there might have been an issue with the VPN, but I still can SSH with my VPN, and the IDE can SSH to the machine and select the project directory, but I get this error:
" Deploy failed, this IDE build has expired"

I have deleted my JetBrains directory in the .cache as well.

with this log:

```
2023-12-03 20:06:24,596 INFO    uname -sm
    stdout:
    Linux x86_64

2023-12-03 20:06:24,841 INFO    echo $SHELL
    stdout:
    /bin/bash

2023-12-03 20:06:25,067 INFO    uname -sm
    stdout:
    Linux x86_64

2023-12-03 20:06:25,340 INFO    echo $SHELL
    stdout:
    /bin/bash

2023-12-03 20:06:25,588 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ echo\ \$HOME
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    /home/hm31

2023-12-03 20:06:25,919 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ echo\ \$XDG_CACHE_HOME
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_

2023-12-03 20:06:26,300 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ test\ -f\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_

2023-12-03 20:06:26,678 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ test\ -x\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_

2023-12-03 20:06:26,982 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64\ get-path\ --path=cache
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains

2023-12-03 20:06:27,364 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64\ get-path\ --path=config
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    /home/hm31/.config/JetBrains

2023-12-03 20:06:27,724 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64\ exists\ --path=/home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    true

2023-12-03 20:06:28,018 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64\ exists\ --path=/home/hm31/.config/JetBrains
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    true

2023-12-03 20:06:28,353 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64\ lock-support
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_

2023-12-03 20:06:28,668 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64\ available-memory
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    263587544

2023-12-03 20:06:28,970 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64\ cpu-count
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    256

2023-12-03 20:06:29,268 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64\ port-forwarding-test
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    46385

2023-12-03 20:06:29,761 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64\ readlink\ --path=/home/hm31/step_1
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    /home/hm31/step_1

2023-12-03 20:06:30,083 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64\ get-path\ --path=cache
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains

2023-12-03 20:06:30,386 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64\ get-path\ --path=config
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    /home/hm31/.config/JetBrains

2023-12-03 20:06:30,704 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64\ exists\ --path=/home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    true

2023-12-03 20:06:31,110 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64\ exists\ --path=/home/hm31/.config/JetBrains
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    true

2023-12-03 20:06:31,424 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64\ get-path\ --path=cache
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains

2023-12-03 20:06:31,726 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64\ get-path\ --path=config
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    /home/hm31/.config/JetBrains

2023-12-03 20:06:32,024 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64\ available-space\ --path=/home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    336547868672

2023-12-03 20:06:32,345 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64\ available-space\ --path=/home/hm31/.config/JetBrains
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    336547868672

2023-12-03 20:06:32,763 WARN    exit code: 1    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64\ host-status\ --ide-path=/home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/882ad45585178_pycharm-professional-233.11555.5\ --project-path=/home/hm31/step_1
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    {"type":"error","errorCode":"CommandError","data":"Command /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/882ad45585178_pycharm-professional-233.11555.5/bin/remote-dev-server.sh failed.\nStdout: IDE config directory: /home/hm31/.config/JetBrains/RemoteDev-PY/_home_hm31_step_1\nIDE system directory: /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev-PY/_home_hm31_step_1\nEnable JDK auto-detection and project SDK setup by default. Set REMOTE_DEV_JDK_DETECTION=false to disable.\nIs running inside Docker container: 0\nCompileCommand: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend bool exclude = true\nThis IDE build has expired. Please download a new build from JetBrains official site\n\nStderr: \n\nCaused by: exit status 7"}

    [command is repeated 20 more times]

2023-12-03 20:07:22,586 WARN    exit code: 1    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64\ host-status\ --ide-path=/home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/882ad45585178_pycharm-professional-233.11555.5\ --project-path=/home/hm31/step_1
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    {"type":"error","errorCode":"CommandError","data":"Command /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/882ad45585178_pycharm-professional-233.11555.5/bin/remote-dev-server.sh failed.\nStdout: IDE config directory: /home/hm31/.config/JetBrains/RemoteDev-PY/_home_hm31_step_1\nIDE system directory: /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev-PY/_home_hm31_step_1\nEnable JDK auto-detection and project SDK setup by default. Set REMOTE_DEV_JDK_DETECTION=false to disable.\nIs running inside Docker container: 0\nCompileCommand: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend bool exclude = true\nThis IDE build has expired. Please download a new build from JetBrains official site\n\nStderr: 2023-12-03 20:07:23,783 [    144]   WARN - #c.i.p.instanceContainer - ApplicationImpl@1767922964 services : com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectStoreFactory is registered and overridden in the same scope (com.intellij.configurationStore.PlatformProjectStoreFactory -\u003e com.intellij.configurationStore.PlatformLangProjectStoreFactory)\n\n\nCaused by: exit status 7"}

2023-12-03 20:07:24,967 WARN    exit code: 1    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64\ host-status\ --ide-path=/home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/882ad45585178_pycharm-professional-233.11555.5\ --project-path=/home/hm31/step_1
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    {"type":"error","errorCode":"CommandError","data":"Command /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/882ad45585178_pycharm-professional-233.11555.5/bin/remote-dev-server.sh failed.\nStdout: IDE config directory: /home/hm31/.config/JetBrains/RemoteDev-PY/_home_hm31_step_1\nIDE system directory: /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev-PY/_home_hm31_step_1\nEnable JDK auto-detection and project SDK setup by default. Set REMOTE_DEV_JDK_DETECTION=false to disable.\nIs running inside Docker container: 0\nCompileCommand: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend bool exclude = true\nThis IDE build has expired. Please download a new build from JetBrains official site\n\nStderr: \n\nCaused by: exit status 7"}

    [command is repeated 3 more times]

2023-12-03 20:07:34,307 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64\ backend-status-alive\ --project-path=/home/hm31/step_1
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    false

2023-12-03 20:07:34,840 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64\ product-code\ --ide-path=/home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/882ad45585178_pycharm-professional-233.11555.5
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    PY

2023-12-03 20:07:35,159 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64\ get-logs-dir\ --product-code=PY\ --project-path=/home/hm31/step_1
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev-PY/_home_hm31_step_1/log

2023-12-03 20:07:35,466 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64\ host-launch\ --ide-path=/home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/882ad45585178_pycharm-professional-233.11555.5\ --project-path=/home/hm31/step_1\ --stdout-file=/home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev-PY/_home_hm31_step_1/log/stdout.log\ --stderr-file=/home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev-PY/_home_hm31_step_1/log/stderr.log
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_

2023-12-03 20:07:38,741 INFO    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64\ backend-host-alive\ --project-path=/home/hm31/step_1
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    false

2023-12-03 20:07:39,239 WARN    exit code: 1    /bin/bash -lc echo\ REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_\ \&\&\ /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_83eb3f8153ed29f38ae607b0a82d4ed8470bcd5f8f346034c4e370bb06d9dd64\ host-status\ --ide-path=/home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/882ad45585178_pycharm-professional-233.11555.5\ --project-path=/home/hm31/step_1
    stdout:
    REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_
    {"type":"error","errorCode":"CommandError","data":"Command /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/882ad45585178_pycharm-professional-233.11555.5/bin/remote-dev-server.sh failed.\nStdout: IDE config directory: /home/hm31/.config/JetBrains/RemoteDev-PY/_home_hm31_step_1\nIDE system directory: /home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev-PY/_home_hm31_step_1\nEnable JDK auto-detection and project SDK setup by default. Set REMOTE_DEV_JDK_DETECTION=false to disable.\nIs running inside Docker container: 0\nCompileCommand: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend bool exclude = true\nThis IDE build has expired. Please download a new build from JetBrains official site\n\nStderr: \n\nCaused by: exit status 7"}


==== FAILURES ====

The following exception failed the deployment
com.jetbrains.gateway.ssh.deploy.DeployException: This IDE build has expired. Provide another build or select 'JetBrains Installer' from the installation options to install the latest version.
    at com.jetbrains.gateway.ssh.DeployFlowUtil$fullDeployCycleImpl$2.invokeSuspend(DeployFlowUtil.kt:303)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at com.intellij.openapi.rd.util.CoroutineProgressContext$Companion$create$task$1$3.invokeSuspend(BackgroundProgressCoroutineUtil.kt:174)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:280)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.openapi.rd.util.CoroutineProgressContext$Companion$create$task$1.invoke(BackgroundProgressCoroutineUtil.kt:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.rd.util.CoroutineProgressContext$Companion$create$task$1.invoke(BackgroundProgressCoroutineUtil.kt:160)
    at com.intellij.openapi.rd.util.CoroutineProgressContext$Companion$createModal$1$1.run(BackgroundProgressCoroutineUtil.kt:205)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.startTask(CoreProgressManager.java:428)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.startTask(ProgressManagerImpl.java:115)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressSynchronously$9(CoreProgressManager.java:512)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$new$0(ProgressRunner.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:251)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$0(ProgressManager.java:71)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:186)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$13(CoreProgressManager.java:604)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:679)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:635)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:603)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:61)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:173)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.runProcess(ProgressManager.java:71)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$5(ProgressRunner.java:251)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$launchTask$18(ProgressRunner.java:465)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: com.jetbrains.gateway.ssh.deploy.DeployException: This IDE build has expired. Provide another build or select 'JetBrains Installer' from the installation options to install the latest version.
    at com.jetbrains.gateway.ssh.DeployFlowUtil$fullDeployCycleImpl$2.invokeSuspend(DeployFlowUtil.kt:298)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: com.jetbrains.gateway.ssh.deploy.DeployException: This IDE build has expired. Provide another build or select 'JetBrains Installer' from the installation options to install the latest version.
    at com.jetbrains.gateway.ssh.DeployFlowUtil$fullDeployCycleImpl$2.invokeSuspend(DeployFlowUtil.kt:293)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: com.jetbrains.gateway.ssh.deploy.DeployException: This IDE build has expired. Provide another build or select 'JetBrains Installer' from the installation options to install the latest version.
    at com.jetbrains.gateway.ssh.deploy.methods.HostRunMethods.getStatusWithSuitableRemoteProject(HostRunMethods.kt:285)
    at com.jetbrains.gateway.ssh.deploy.methods.HostRunMethods$getStatusWithSuitableRemoteProject$1.invokeSuspend(HostRunMethods.kt)
    ... 37 more



==== ENVIRONMENT ====

INSTALLED PRODUCTS

    PyCharm 233.11555.5


AVAILABLE MEMORY

    251.38GB



==== DIAGNOSTIC ERRORS ====

Could not get host jstack: 

Details:
An error occurred while executing command: 'get-jstack --ide-path=/home/hm31/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/882ad45585178_pycharm-professional-233.11555.5 --project-path=/home/hm31/step_1'
Exit code: 1
```

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/10898451233682-Remote-development-SSH-connection

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Thank you it worked!
I had checked this link earlier and deleted JetBrains in .cache but didn't work
I tried switching IDE to the latest version that worked.